# Do Thunderbird 3-to-USB 3.1 Type-C adapters/converters for external hard drives exist?

Tags: linux, windows, usb, external-hard-drive, thunderbird

MSI GE73 7RD Raider has an USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type-C port and 3x USB 3.0 Type-A (no idea about the gen) ports, but no Thunderbolt ports of any kind. My desktop should eventually have an USB Type-C.

Not to mention the machine runs either Win10 or Xubuntu LTS Linux, not a Mac.

But I'm looking to buy either a Thunderbolt 3 or an USB 3.1 Type-C external HDD, or if everything fails an USB 3.0 Type-A one.

**To that end, can I connect a Thunderbolt 3 to USB 3.1 Type-C (or USB 3.0 Type-A) somehow ?**

Comment: USB 3.0 was renamed to USB 3.1 Gen 1.

Comment: You understand that Thunderbolt to USB 3.1 Gen 1 would significantly impact the performance of Thubderbolt?  You would be better off getting a Thunderbolt PCIe card and using Thunderbolt.  This also might answer your question: https://thunderbolttechnology.net/blog/difference-between-usb-c-and-thunderbolt-3

Comment: @Ramhound Judging by https://www.benq.com/en/knowledge-center/knowledge/thunderbolt3-usb3-1-gen2-type-c.html and https://www.gbmb.org/gbps-to-mbs it won't matter going from Tb3 to USB 3.1 Gen 2 cuz you won't be able to use the 5½GB/s speed Tb3 provides nor the 1.25GB/s USB 3.1 Gen 2 provides, so it'll be perfectly fine for hard drive use. Hell, even going for a RAID system would mostly be fine by the speed alone. 3.1 Gen 1, sure.

Comment: A TB3 host controller can drive USB 3.x devices, it is a superset of USB3 and understands it. The opposite is not true: a USB 3.x host can't drive TB3 devices. I don't think anyone in sober mind will try to make a special silicon bridge to accommodate TB3 devices in USB3 host.